# uploaded a debuggable APK message when exporting from android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to export the signed apk from Android studio, I tried following steps

1) choose the build variant "Release"

2) Modified the build.gradle file

3) In manifest file there is no where debuggable==true

still i am getting same message when trying to upload to the playstore. Below is what my build.gradle file code looks like

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.XXXXX.XXXXX"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {

            debuggable false

        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'proguard.cfg'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':andEngineLiveWallpaperExtension')
    compile project(':liveWallPaperBaseSettings')
}
```

Do i need to do the change in all build.gradle of other library modules which is used by the main app module? or am i missing something?

Comment: Have you created a keystore for the application? Goto Build -> Generate Signed APK if not and follow that wizard.

Comment: Also, be sure you are selecting the right APK when uploading to the playstore. It should have a '-release' postfix if it is a release.

Comment: @MichaelGarner Yes, I am doing that way only.I already have old keystore and before i was using eclipse and now i am trying to migrate to android studio and export the apk using old keystore, Also the apk have postfix '-release' but when i try to upload its showing same message.

Comment: Let's see full gradle file.

Comment: @MichaelGarner Added full gradle file above, If i am using other modules as dependencies, Do i need to change their build variant also to release, or else only the main app module need to be set as release?

Comment: You should only need to change the build variant for your app. Your gradle file looks fine too. You mentioned you were using an old keystore. Have you verified that that keystore is not the debug keystore? Each project will have a debug keystore automatically. You will need to use a keystore created by a person to do a signed release. If you are using a non-debug keystore, try generating a new one through Android Studio's wizard and see if that works to create a release build.

Comment: When Android Studio creates a release APK it actually creates two. One is postfixed 'release-unsigned' or similar and the other is just 'release'. Make sure you're selecting the latter for GooglePlay. Also, to check keystore you may need to create a 'new app'. Just don't publish it.

Comment: I am not using any debug keystore, i am using same keystore which i used with eclipse to publish my apps earlier, after buliding the apk, i am getting appname-release.apk file, but still google play is showing me same error saying its a debug apk.I have checked my many documents, I hope am doing it right but still i am failing.

Comment: Unfortunately short of being there and trying a few things and getting my eyes on it, I don't think I can help anymore. I made the conversion from Eclipse to Android Studio, but I don't recall running into this issue. The only other thing I can think of to check is the alias when using the keystore. You can have multiple aliases in a single keystore. One of which could be the 'debug' alias. When generating signed APK, enter the first password for the keystore and then there should be an option to browse aliases. Ensure that you're selecting the non-debug alias.

Comment: That's the only thing I can think of at this point though.

Comment: @MichaelGarner For me there is only a single Alias and i use seperate keystore for each apps.Lets see if anything else am missing, Thank you for the help anyways ^^

Comment: @MichaelGarner Problem was inside one of the library module manifest I saw debuggable==true, I don't know how library module manifest overrides the main app module manifest though. Anyway i uploaded the apk successfully to play-store. Thanks a lot for the help :)